# Zlib Inflate -3 Z_DATA_ERROR randomly

Tags: c, zlib, compression, inflate

I am trying to decompress a file with zlib inflate()(which is also used for compression).At that time i got "Incorrect Data Check".When i compared the checksum values, the values are different.So,i thought the data may be invalid.But after some time i tried to decompress the same file at that time it shows "invalid block type".Its seems like strange.The file is received over the network socket (TCP).This error came randomly.Not every time.

When i saw the file data ,
It looks like instead of my original data "**.......y.p.q.?/1**" this data is coming "**z.Free.y.p.q.?**".

It seems like zfree() in zlib.It corrupted the data while compressing/decompressing? Is this right?Or any other reason for this?

Comment: You'd need to provide more data in your question.  zlib inflate is entirely deterministic, so there is something else going on.  Can you provide a short code example and input data the exhibits the issue you are observing?

Comment: Hi Adler,Thanks for the response.Sorry.At present i cant share the code with you.Whatever the file data that i mentioned in the question "z.Free.y.p.q".It is taken from the network(It is a network data) while receiving from the remote partner.So,is there any chance to embed this z.Free function during compression or while sending ?And is there any chances   like   some other process interuupting this process and overwrite the data with z.Free() function?

Comment: I think there is a issue in 1.1.3 version of zlib (http://www.zlib.net/advisory-2002-03-11.txt ).So,is there any possibility of this version may cause this issue?

Comment: No. That has no bearing on the determinacy of inflate.

Comment: Hi Adler,Thanks for the quick response.do you think this is not related with compression/decompression and may be because of network data or OS level data corruption?

Comment: This is not related to the compression / decompression.

Comment: Thanks Adler for your response.

Comment: We dont have any data like "z.Free"  in our file.So,what are all the chances of adding this z.Free in the data/buffer while transferring over the network?

Comment: That has nothing to do with zlib.

Comment: Too much storytelling, not enough code